# JMeter 3.1 generate dashboard report without sbadmin2 folder

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, dashboard

How can I generate the JMeter HTML/dashboard report without having always generated and saved the sbadmin2 folder that is needed for the bootstrap layout? Also, where does the import of the results into the index.html file happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're asking for does not exist, I've created this enhancement request for it:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61458

It should not be to hard to add if it's needed.